# .net System.Security.SecurityElement class convert &quot; to /"

Tags: c#, .net

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8xPE.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGM5S.jpg)

The two images are snapshot of the same code in the same project. One is debugging on the server and the other is on local develop machine.
The inputs are totally the same. You can see from the images,`SecurityElement c` are the same, but the property's value is "nimda" the other one's value is \"nimda\".
Both are running on windows with .net framework 3.5. Why the properties have different values with a same input?

Comment: Image 1 and Image 2 seem to point to same image.

Comment: I edit your image links, please make sure it's what you want.